# Extract element from JSON array in file with jq

Tags: bash, json, jq

I have the following JSON file `list.json` :

```
[
  {
    "$type": "Profile",
    "ReferenceId": "6e374d9e-5bbe-4015-acd7-ae6f04de0db5",
    "Name": " aaa"
  },
  {
    "$type": "Profile",
    "ReferenceId": "5c055f82-696b-48c2-9b7f-a540d48fcd19",
    "Name": " bbb"
  }
 ]
```

In bash, I would like to extract in variable the value of the first occurance of the key "ReferenceId" where the key "Name" equal "bbb".

I tried `jq -r ".[] | select(.Name==\"bbb?take=300") | .ReferenceId" < list.json` but nothing works. I suppose i need to use --slurpfile but I don't see how to do that.

Thx in advance for your replies.

Comment: The file example you give and the search criteria do not match up. In fact, there is even a syntax error in the command. When changing examples, please make extra sure they are still a valid representation of your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring the broken JSON (no comma allowed on the last key:value pair) and that the Name does not equal "bbb" (there's a space):

```sh
jq -r 'map(select(.Name == " bbb")) | first | .ReferenceId' list.json
```

If you want "the name *contains* bbb" then `select(.Name | contains("bbb"))`